# Ubuntu terminal not exporting environment variable from .bashrc

Tags: 13.04, bashrc

I tried adding this to *.profile*:

```
export OSTYPE=linux
```

but the output of `echo $OSTYPE` is still `linux-gnu`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add "export OSTYPE=linux in your .bashrc

```
sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
```

add the line

close terminal then reopen

```
echo $OSTYPE
linux
```

[image]

Comment: i have done this, but still getting linux-gnu

Comment: you added in .profile as stated in your question not in .bashrc

Comment: i have added "export OSTYPE=linux" in both files(.bashrc and .profile)

Comment: remove from .profile then restart your terminal emulator

Comment: DONE what u mentioned in above comment, but still OSTYPE is linux-gnu

Comment: add it to your .bashrc without export and reopen terminal

Comment: tried "OSTYPE=linux" in .bashrc,close and reopend terminal, but it not worked

Comment: so how can i correct this ?